# AnyLogic - how to create a custom experiment

Tags: anylogic

I've built my first agent-based model with AnyLogic and now I need to calibrate it. I tried with the available experiments but it takes too long and I cannot simulate more than 10.000 agents. So I want to try with a custom experiment...but I have no clue on how to built it!

I built a very simple model
[image]
where parameter is `bernoulli(main.calib)` and then I want to maximize the number of agents that go the the final state.

I copied the code from the experiments available from the help and did some minor adjustments

```
try {
// Create Engine, initialize random number generator:
Engine engine = createEngine();
// Set stop time:
engine.setStopTime( 2 );

// Create optimization variable 
final COptQuestContinuousVariable v = new COptQuestContinuousVariable();
v.SetLowerBound(0.0);
v.SetUpperBound(1.0);

// Create objective
final COptQuestObjective obj = new COptQuestUserControlledObjective();
obj.SetMaximize();

// Create optimization engine
final COptQuestOptimization opt = ExperimentOptimization.createOptimization(engine, new OptimizationCallback() {

    @Override
    public void evaluate(COptQuestOptimization optimization,
            COptQuestSolution solution, Engine engine) {
        try {
            // Create new root object:
            Main root = new Main( engine, null, null );
            // Setup parameters of root object here
            root.calib = solution.GetVariableValue(v);
            // Prepare Engine for simulation:
            engine.start( root );
            // Start simulation in fast mode:
            engine.runFast();
            // Process results of simulation here
            solution.SetObjectiveValue( obj, root.end );
            // Destroy the model:
            engine.stop();
        } catch (COptQuestException e) {
            traceln(e.Description());
        }
    }

    // Trace each iteration (optional!)
    @Override
    public void monitorStatus(COptQuestOptimization optimization,
            COptQuestSolution solution, Engine engine) {
        try {
            traceln(String.format("  %3d : %6.2f : %8.2f  -- %8.2f",
                solution.GetIteration(), solution.GetVariableValue(v),
                solution.GetObjectiveValue(),
                optimization.GetBestSolution() != null ?
                optimization.GetBestSolution().GetObjectiveValue(obj) : Double.NaN));
        } catch (COptQuestException e) {
            traceln(e.Description());
        }
    }

});

// Setup optimization engine
opt.AddVariable(v);
opt.AddObjective(obj);
// Set the number of iterations to run
opt.SetMaximumIterations(30);

// Add suggested solution (initial solution)
COptQuestSolution suggestedSolution = opt.CreateSolution();
suggestedSolution.SetVariableValue(v, 0.5);
opt.AddSuggestedSolution(suggestedSolution);

traceln(" Iter : Param  : Objective -- Best obj.");
traceln("-------------------------------------------");
// Perform optimization
opt.Optimize();
traceln("-------------------------------------------");

// Output results
COptQuestSolution bestSolution = opt.GetBestSolution();
traceln("Best objective: " + format(bestSolution.GetObjectiveValue(obj)));
traceln("   is feasible: " + format(bestSolution.IsFeasible()));
traceln("Best parameter: " + format(bestSolution.GetVariableValue(v)));
traceln("Best iteration: " + bestSolution.GetIteration());
```

`} catch (COptQuestException e)   {
        traceln(e.Description());
    }`

and the following is the result...

[image]

I don't get why the objective is always zero...

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: i haven't worked with the custom experiment that much. mostly with parameter variations. But where are you telling the experiment about the number of agents in the final stage?

Answer (score 0):

The Personal Learning Edition of AnyLogic has some limits on how many agents can do certain things, and it ALSO does not allow custom experiments. Maybe AnyLogic is silently failing. Just a shot in the dark, as I'm not a regular AnyLogic user.